# PHP ldap_* API: Limiting to base scope?

Tags: php, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

So [The Direct Project](http://wiki.directproject.org/) strikes again. I'm no expert in LDAP, but I'm trying to set up a test environment since the standard requires any package to support getting certificates from LDAP as well as DNS CERT, regardless of which method is implemented by the package.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1igDpIizm7CTfV-fUw_1EnrCUGIljFEgLPRHpgK5iaec/edit), the prescribed sequence of events (trimmed for relevance) from section "3.3.3 LDAP query":

```
* Discover the Base DNs
     Branches in LDAP must be defined by a “Base DN”. The list of Base DNs that are
     provided by a LDAP directory are found by doing a LDAP Query with a NULL (i.e.
     “”) Base DN, and ObjectClass=”DN”.
* Query across the Base DN for entries where "Mail" contains the endpoint address
```

I'm trying to implement this process in php, using the ldap_* functions, but their way doesn't seem to work. Obviously, NULL is not the same as an empty string (the latter makes any call to ldap_search return a "No such object" error), and "DN" isn't a valid value for an ObjectClass attribute.

So, TL;DR, is there another way an anonymous remote user retrieve the (list of?) base DNs that I'm missing?

UPDATE: Reworded the title to reflect the root cause of my problem: Reading the rootDSE from PHP when the ldap_* api doesn't allow you to specify 'base' scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So another read through the docs answered my question for me.

Apparently, the only difference between ldap_search(), ldap_list(), and ldap_read() are the scopes (LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE (sub), LDAP_SCOPE_ONELEVEL (one), and LDAP_SCOPE_BASE (base), respectively). So using ldap_read() instead of the others will allow one to get the rootDSE.

Comment: I was going to, but it made me wait 2 days. The low reputation, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In the [root dse](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html). See "namingContexts".

#### Update:

In java:

```
LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection(hostname,port);
SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest("",SearchScope.BASE,"(&)","+");
SearchResult result = conn.search(req);

// If the search succeeds, the result will comprise one entry,
// and that entry is the Root DSE:

dn: 
subschemaSubentry: cn=schema
namingContexts: C=us
vendorName: UnboundID Corp.
vendorVersion: UnboundID Directory Server 4.1.0.6
```

Comment: According that link, "an LDAP-compliant directory server is not permitted to return attributes from the root DSE if the base object is not ('') or the search scope is not 'base'" but I can't find any way of changing the scope for ldap_search() or ldap_list(), which would otherwise appear to be the right functions to call for this.

Comment: My article simply meant that you can use the null/empty string as the base object, but that the server must not return the root DSE unless the scope is `base`. If you set the base object to `""` and the scope to `sub` you should get the entire DIT, assuming the server permits that kind of trawling. I'm not sure how to do that in your API, but it should be simple enough to use `""` for the base object, right. I can't imagine an API where you couldn't change the base object, filter, scope, or requested attributes.

Comment: No need to imagine it. [It exists!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php) >_<

Comment: That's very strange. I had never looked at the PHP LDAP implementation, and you are correct: there appears to be no way to change the scope in `ldap_search`. In any case, you cannot retrieve the root DSE with using `base` scope. Can you use an alternative language?

Comment: That should be: "you cannot retrieve the root DSE WITHOUT using base scope."

Comment: Not for the codebase. I'll have to investigate ways of either "extending" PHP, or doing the raw LDAP with sockets.